# Spring Boot - Do a new WebClient call with result of another call

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to call an api with 2 call using webclient.
The first call return a token.
The second call use the token.

```java
public Mono<GetToken> getToken{
 return webClient
      .get()
      .uri(uriBuilder ->
        uriBuilder
          .path("api/getToken")
          .build()
      )
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(Object.class);
}
```

```
public Mono<GetToken> getData{
 return webClient
      .get()
      .uri(uriBuilder ->
        uriBuilder
          .path("api/getData/"+tokenID)
          .build()
      )
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(Object2.class);
}
```

How can I use the data from the first request in the second without using the block() function

Comment: You mean like putting the call to `getData()` in `.flatMap()`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Mono#flatMap`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-).

```java
Mono<Object2> res = getToken().flatMap(token -> getData(token));
```